# What are the cmd and powershell equivalent commands for the following grep?

Tags: powershell, cmd, grep

In `cmd`, the `grep` equivalent is `findstr` and in `powershell` the `grep` equivalent is `select-string`. I know the following `grep` command achieve the result, I am looking for:

`grep -RH ".*Echo.*" --include="*.nb" *`

Can someone tell me how to achieve this in `cmd` and `powershell`?

---

This code `grep -RH ".*Echo.*" --include="*.nb" *` recursively searches the current directory and all sub directories looking for files that match the pattern `"*.nb"` and then looks inside the matched files for the regular expression `".*Echo.*"`.

If the match is found it prints a two column data delimited by `:` for columns and `\r\n` for rows. The first column contains the path to the file and second column contains the entire row where match is found.

If the same file contains multiple rows with matches it repeats them in the dataset returned.

Comment: please describe what that code does and we can pro'ly tell you how to do it with PoSh. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey code working description added!

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `findstr /?` and read the output help. For example: `findstr /I /L /S "echo" *.nb` There is no need to run a regular expression search if just all lines containing case insensitive `echo` found in all *.nb files in current directory and all subdirectories should be output by `findstr`. Please click on gray displayed __delete__ link to delete your question being off-topic for Stack Overflow according to help topic [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Thank you.

Comment: @user13892 - thank you for that. it makes thinking about it lots easier when i don't have to go read the MAN pages ... [*grin*]

Comment: PS: In a Windows command prompt run `help` for a brief overview of available [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and run a command with parameter `/?` to get displayed its help. Or look on referenced Microsoft documentation or even better [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/).

Comment: PowerShell `gci *.nb -rec|sls 'echo'` will output 3 colon delimited columns file,linenumber,line, to have a 2 column csv file use `gci *.nb -rec|sls 'echo'|select path,line|export-csv yourname.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
get-childitem -recurse -Filter "*.nb" -file | select-string -Pattern "Echo" | %{"{0}:{1}" -f $_.Path, $_.Line}
```

Short version :

```
gci -rec -Filter "*.txt" -file | sls "Echo" | %{"{0}:{1}" -f $_.Path, $_.Line}
```

Comment: Nice, though you should add `-CaseSensitive` to match `grep`'s case-sensitive-by-default behavior.